# How to reference the bundled js files (asp.net mvc4) in Require.js?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, requirejs, durandal, bundling-and-minification, toastr

I have been studying John Papa's pluralsight course on SPA.

In his `main.js`, he gave a name to each js library which is included in the bundle.

```
(function () {
var root = this;

define3rdPartyModules();


function define3rdPartyModules() {
    // These are already loaded via bundles. 
    // We define them and put them in the root object.
    define('jquery', [], function () { return root.jQuery; });
    define('ko', [], function () { return root.ko; });
    define('amplify', [], function () { return root.amplify; });
    define('infuser', [], function () { return root.infuser; });
    define('moment', [], function () { return root.moment; });
    define('sammy', [], function () { return root.Sammy; });
    define('toastr', [], function () { return root.toastr; });
    define('underscore', [], function () { return root._; });
}

})();
```

But what is the `root` here?

---

By doing so, we can call those short names in the `define` statement:

```
define('vm.session',
['ko', 'datacontext', 'config', 'router', 'messenger', 'sort'],
function (ko, datacontext, config, router, messenger, sort) {
```

Current, I don't know how to do that. So my working `define` statement is ugly:

```
define('vm.admin.outfitters',
['/Scripts/lib/jquery-1.8.1.js', '/Scripts/lib/jsrender.js', ...], function(){...
```

I know there's gotta be a better way. All those js files have been included in the script bundle already. How can I reference those scripts?

Comment: Hi @Blaise... I'm trying to use bundling and minification with requirejs, but I have no clue on how to put it to work! Do you have any sample code that you could provide me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**RE: root**

RequireJS and the AMD ready libraries remove the objects from the global scope (things like ko). Some plugins want them in global scope, so we can either shim those plugins or pop the objects back in global scope. The latter is what is happening in this code. It's being done for the plugins for Knockout primarily.

**RE: your define statements**

The first parameter is the name of of the module, so you are fine there. THe second parameter is the list of modules that RequireJS is aware of. The 3rd parameter is the matching variable to represent it. So in your code you might have something like this ...

```
define('vm.admin.outfitters',
['jquery', 'jsrender'], function($, jsrender) {
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it appears that I have made it work. But it still is confusing to me. BTW, your course is valuable, but just a little too fast-paced for many of us. :-)