# Reference bundles on requirejs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, requirejs, bundling-and-minification

I have an old web application that already uses bundling and minification of ASP.Net MVC.

Now I'm starting to use requirejs and I have a problem! How can I reference bundle files from requirejs?

I know that there is another similar question, but it does not answer to my question!

[How to reference the bundled js files (asp.net mvc4) in Require.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414654/how-to-reference-the-bundled-js-files-asp-net-mvc4-in-require-js/12428681)

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping that I understand your question correctly.

If your bundle contains `requireJS modules` and you're loading it on the page, you can still call those `modules` as long as you've defined them like I have below:

Let's say your existing bundle is being rendered like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/aCustomBundle")
```

The bundle contains `jQuery`, `React` and a `aLibrary` module. The `aLibrary` is defined as follows in that bundle.

```
// Define custom modules
define('aLibrary', [], function() {
   return {
      aFunction: function() {
           console.log('a function within a library');
      }
   }
});
```

In your page, you can call that module and define the third-party libraries like this.

```
<script>
    // Third party libraries
    define('jquery', [], function () { return jQuery; });
    define('react', [], function () { return React; });

    // Use the libs from the bundle
    require(['aLibrary', 'jquery', 'react'], function(a, j, r) {

       // Execute the function from the aLibrary
       a.aFunction();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I notice you have used the three argument signature for require, and you have specified a name. If this is pivotal then maybe you should edit the example to read `define('aLibraryName'...)` referenced `require(['aLibraryName',...` Also, if naming libs is the trick to using them out of bundles, what do you do with existing third party libs that lack names? Is there some kind of wrapper technique or would we have to edit them to have a name?